# Rails 3.1 force .html instead of no extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

One of my clients wants his new Rails application to look more like his traditional web site.  He wants to know if I can force urls to have a file extension, preferably `.html`.

I don't want to hard-code the extension in `routes.rb` as

```
match ':controller/:action/:id.html'
```

(or similar) because the client also wants to have a `respond_to`-style JSON API which requires the use of `.:format`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as Mattias Wadman suggested, in `config/application.rb` add:

```
AppName::Application.default_url_options = { :format => "html" }
```

But also change `config/routes.rb` to:

```
root :to => 'pages#home', :defaults => { :format => "html" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Im no Rails routing expert but I tried to force HTML format by changing the default URL options and at least the URL helpers seams to generate .html URLs now, it's a start.

config/application.rb (at the bottom)

```
AppName::Application.default_url_options = {:format => "html"}
```

Comment: Hmm seams to work for me, weird. do you see ...(.:format) for your routes when running `rake routes`?

Comment: Output of `rake routes`: `/:action(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>":action"}` and `root / {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}`. (I can't break it up onto multiple lines in a comment.)  Using `link_to ...` works but using `<%= root_url %>` returns `http://server:3000/?format=html`

Comment: If you look at the source for the [root](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/root) route match you will see that it does not include `:format`. But you can replace it with `match '/(.:format)', :to => 'pages#root', :as => :root` etc. But then `root_url` will be `"http://www.example.com/.html"`, probably not what you want?

Comment: That's not what I want but I could just not use `root_url` and redirect `/` to `/home.html` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I want to give it until the end of the week to see if anyone else has any ideas.  If not, I'll mark this as the answer.