# How to define default format for link_to in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I already see some similar quetions:

[How to set the default format for a route in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800219/how-to-set-the-default-format-for-a-route-in-rails)

[Rails 3 respond_to: default format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643738/rails-3-respond-to-default-format)

[Rails 3.1 force .html instead of no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403826/rails-3-1-force-html-instead-of-no-extension)

But any solution didn't work in rails 4 for me:

in `routers.rb`

```
 :defaults => { :format => 'html' }
```

in `app/controllers/some_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :set_format

def set_format
  request.format = 'html'
end
```

in `config/application.rb`

```
config.default_url_options = { :format => "html" }
```

Any of there. I tried all it together and each separate.

Here my code:

```
link_to("Read more", article_path(article, :format => "html"))
# => <a href="/1.html">Read more</a>
```

What will be if I remove `:format => "html"`:

```
link_to("Read more", article_path(article))
# => <a href="/1">Read more</a>
```

What I am want:

```
link_to("Read more", article_path(article))
# => <a href="/1.html">Read more</a>
```

Share your suggestion for it, please.

Comment: I see that default formal is `xml`, and you need to override it as `html`, so why you don't want to write `:format => "html"` every time ?

Comment: Why do you force request format to xml?

Comment: @mohamed-yakot, thanks, correct question. It was a copypaste mistake

Comment: @michal-szyndel, thanks to you too. fix question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use add these options to your route, I think you'll end up with the `.html` in the path like you want. You shouldn't even need to modify your call to `article_path`.

```
format: true, defaults: { format: 'html' }
```

---

I ran into something similar. Looking through the Rails [routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) helped me find an answer.

I have an action which I want to default to the CSV format, but I also want to generate the URL with the `.csv` in it. This way the client can tell, just by looking at the URL, that it's a CSV. Without the `.csv`, it's not very clear what the link will be.

My route was something like this:

```
get 'customers/with_favorite_color/:color' => 'customers#with_favorite_color', as: :customers_with_favorite_color, format: 'csv'
```

And I was generating the link like this:

```
customers_with_favorite_color_url(color: 'blue', format: :csv)
# => `http://localhost:3000/customers/with_favorite_color/blue
```

Except, I want `http://localhost:3000/customers/with_favorite_color/blue.csv`.

It seemed that the format would not be added to the URL if that format was also specified in the route.

To get this to work, I changed my route to

```
get 'customers/with_favorite_color/:color' => 'customers#with_favorite_color', as: :customers_with_favorite_color, format: true, defaults: { format: 'csv' }
```

Notice the options added/changed are: `format: true, defaults: { format: 'csv' }`

And now, when I generate the URL, I get the `.csv` appended like I wanted.

```
customers_with_favorite_color_url(color: 'blue')
# => `http://localhost:3000/customers/with_favorite_color/blue.csv
```

---

**Update**

To apply this to many routes, you can follow the advice of [How to set default format for routing in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21016987/249218) and use a scope with these defaults.

```
scope format: true, defaults: { format: 'html' } do
  # Define your resources here like normal
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'd mark it as a right one. Only one single question: do you find the way to define it (`format: true, defaults: { format: 'html' }`) globally? I mean for the whole project?

Comment: I believe you can define this globally by following the advice here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/21016987/249218

Comment: I updated my answer with that additional information.